# Scale up an SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

I have this map of Pennsylvania I'm working on. I currently have a few counties highlighted and on hover it shows the county names. I'd like to add a slight scale increase upon hover. But when set that, it moves the entire path.

Here's a URL to show what's going on. As you hover you'll notice the issue, that's with a scale of 1.2 applied upon hover:

http://ryanharris.works/d/testmap.html

Is there anyway to scale the path but keep it in the same spot? I'm not too familiar with SVG as this is my first practice project.

Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: There are a few ways that I know of - define the transform origin to the center of each element or <g>, translate -x,-y and scale, or matrix transform with -cx,-cy. Raphael.js has helped me with this sort of thing http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

```
transform : scale(...);
transform-origin: ... ;
```

(Need to be prefixed)

Comment: transform origin was the key! Thanks @lateek35